# Pilot freight tracking macro working on one computer but not another

Tags: vba, excel

Recently our office upgraded to new laptops. Luckily in changing over from Windows 7 to 10 and from desktop to Laptops we did not experience any issues with running this macro other than needing to enable popups on Pilotdelivers.com. For a few weeks now we've run this macro on two different laptops and everything has gone smoothly.

Today, on one of the laptops the macro is no longer working correctly, but on the other it's fine. I checked to make sure popups were enabled and that both computers are running from the same excel worksheet on our network. I restarted the computer twice and ran the macro with no other applications open. Laptops are the same model, installed at the same time. Identical software installations and updates. The laptop that is having trouble is used by my less computer savvy co worker and the laptop that's working is mine. So it's possible that there's some setting he changed that he shouldn't have, but I'm not sure what to check.

It seems like it's skipping the portion of code that clicks a link to open a new tab.

What the macro is supposed to do:

1. copy the tracking number on the worksheet
2. open IE
3. insert the tracking number into the text box
4. click track
5. wait for the new page to load
6. click the tracking number link
7. wait for the new tab to load
8. close the first tab
9. check to see if the most recent update is DELIVERED
10. if yes it switches back to excel and inputs DELIVERED and the
     delivery date, if not it looks at the most recent update and adds
     that line to the worksheet.

What seems like the macro is doing:

1. copy the tracking number on the worksheet
2. open IE
3. insert the tracking number into the text box
4. click track
5. wait for the new page to load
6. seems to skip clicking on the tracking number link
7. wait for the current page to load (which is already loaded)
8. when looking for the latest update it grabs the tracking number
   instead (since it's not the expected page)
9. check to see if it's marked DELIVERED
   10.if yes it switches back to excel and inputs DELIVERED and the
   delivery date, if not it looks at the most recent update and adds
   that line to the worksheet

It seems like it skips some or all of this section of code:

```
Dim ieDOC As HTMLDocument
Set ieDOC = ie.document

Set htmlColl = ieDOC.getElementsByTagName("a")
For Each htmlInput In htmlColl
    If htmlInput.ID = "clickElement" Then
        htmlInput.Click
    Exit For
    End If
Next htmlInput

ie.Quit

Set shellWins = New ShellWindows
If shellWins.Count > 0 Then
    Set ie2 = shellWins.Item(1)
End If
```

Full code below:

```
Sub PilotTracking()
Dim ProURL As String
Dim ie As Object
Dim ie2 As Object
Dim RowCount As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim html_Document As HTMLDocument
Dim htmlColl As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
Dim htmlInput As MSHTML.HTMLInputElement
Dim shellWins As ShellWindows
Dim htmlColl2 As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
Dim htmlInput2 As MSHTML.HTMLInputElement
Dim marker As Integer

RowCount = 0
ProURL = "http://www.pilotdelivers.com/"

Do While Not ActiveCell.Offset(RowCount, -5).Value = ""

Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.application")

With ie
    .Visible = True
    .navigate ProURL
    Do Until Not ie.Busy And ie.readyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop
End With

Set Doc = ie.document 'works don't delete

Doc.getElementById("tbShipNum").innerHTML = ActiveCell.Offset(RowCount, -5).Value 'works don't delete

Doc.getElementById("btnTrack").Click 'works don't delete

Do Until Not ie.Busy And ie.readyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop

i = 0
Do While i < 4
    WaitHalfSec
    i = i + 1
Loop

Do Until Not ie.Busy And ie.readyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop

Dim ieDOC As HTMLDocument
Set ieDOC = ie.document

Set htmlColl = ieDOC.getElementsByTagName("a")
For Each htmlInput In htmlColl
    If htmlInput.ID = "clickElement" Then
        htmlInput.Click
    Exit For
    End If
Next htmlInput

ie.Quit


Set shellWins = New ShellWindows
If shellWins.Count > 0 Then
    Set ie2 = shellWins.Item(1)
End If

i = 0
Do While i < 8
    WaitHalfSec
    i = i + 1
Loop

Do Until Not ie2.Busy And ie2.readyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop

Set htmlColl2 = ie2.document.getElementsByTagName("td")
For Each htmlInput2 In htmlColl2
    If htmlInput2.className = "dxgv" Then
        If ActiveCell.Offset(RowCount).Value = "" Then
            ActiveCell.Offset(RowCount).Value = htmlInput2.innerText
        Else
            If ActiveCell.Offset(RowCount).Value <> "DELIVERED" Then
                ActiveCell.Offset(RowCount, -2).Value = ""
            Else
                ActiveCell.Offset(RowCount, -2).Value = htmlInput2.innerText
            End If
            Exit For
        End If
    End If
Next htmlInput2

ie2.Quit
Set shellWins = Nothing
Set ie = Nothing
Set ie2 = Nothing

RowCount = RowCount + 1

Loop

Set shellWins = Nothing
Set ie = Nothing
Set ie2 = Nothing

End Sub

Sub WaitHalfSec()
    Dim t As Single
    t = Timer + 1 / 2
        Do Until t < Timer: DoEvents: Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: I had another account, but I can't remember the log in. That being said I am still fairly new to coding. Almost all that I know I learned by myself on the job by googling, so my knowledge is only to very specific things. Thank you though. I was worried my post was too long.

Comment: True. I was hoping someone might give insight to what else could be causing the error. Also I removed the macro tag from my post.

Comment: There is an IE setting that might relate to whether some links open in new tabs, new windows or the existing tab. Open IE11, click the gear icon then choose Internet Options > General tab > Tabs and look at the "Open links from other programs in" setting to see if it differs between the two laptops.  As you mentioned pop-ups, you might want to check the "When a pop-up is encountered" setting as well. It might also be worth manually checking a tracking number on that website on each laptop to see if anything works differently between the two

Comment: Thank you for your response; however, I have checked both of these options and I haven't been able to find any differences. I double checked was version and update we have on IE as well since he uses it frequently and I don't, but it's exactly the same. Walking through the tracking process manually on each laptop also looks exactly the same. Each laptop when I click the link it opens in a new tab that is still in the same window as the original tab.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

```
Set htmlColl = ieDOC.getElementsByTagName("a")
For Each htmlInput In htmlColl
    If htmlInput.ID = "clickElement" Then
        htmlInput.Click
    Exit For
    End If
Next htmlInput
```

You should be able to just do this:

```
 ieDOC.getElementById("clickElement").Click
```

`Id` is supposed to be unique within a given page.  I see you've used `getElementById` elsewhere, so was there some reason it's not used here?

I'd guess maybe the problem is this:

```
ie.Quit
```

so try commenting that out. Something to do perhaps with where new pages load (new window vs new tab?)

If you're having problems grabbing the correct IE document, then try something like:

```
Function GetIE(sLocation As String) As Object

    Dim objShell As Object, objShellWindows As Object, o As Object
    Dim sURL As String
    Dim retVal As Object

    Set retVal = Nothing
    Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    Set objShellWindows = objShell.Windows

    For Each o In objShellWindows
        sURL = ""
        On Error Resume Next
        'check the URL and if it's the one you want then
        ' assign it to the return value and exit the loop
        sURL = o.document.Location
        On Error GoTo 0
        If sURL Like sLocation & "*" Then
            Set retVal = o
            Exit For
        End If
    Next o
    Set GetIE = retVal

End Function
```

This function will return an IE window which matches the provided URL (i.e. the first on whose URL begins with the passed `sLocation` string)

Comment: I had previously tried commenting out ie.quit to no avail, sorry forgot to mention that in the post. Using your suggested ieDOC.getElementsById("clickElement").Click results in Runtime error 438, object doesn't support this property or method. As for the shell windows suggestion I'll have to try that tomorrow, but I feel like that's not the issue either. The new tab never opens, as if the button wasn't clicked. Not that there are 2 pages to choose from and it's going to the wrong one. It's just going to the only one. Could this even be a code problem since it works on mine but not his?

Comment: It may be a timing issue: maybe experiment with al onger delay than two seconds.  Quitting IE immediately after clicking the link is not a good plan I think, so I would also address that.  `ShellWindows`  includes Windows Explorer windows, so maybe the macro is grabbing one of those instead of your intended IE window: if your colleague has windows explorer open but you typically don't then that might explain the differences.  I'm on Win7 so can't really test in any way that's going to closely mimic your setup.

Comment: Slight typo: (incorrect) `getElementsById` in the code block but (correct) `getElementById` in the text. Going by their comment on this answer, @SarahDawnLewis has used the incorrect version

Comment: @barrowc - fixed my typo - thanks for the correction

Comment: Neither the correct not incorrect version of getElementByID seems to be working on either laptop. I'm not sure why. I double checked to make sure everything matched the getElementByID that I use earlier in my code and it does other than variable names. I haven't been able to test out the shell windows code yet, I've been in meetings. For some reason when I change the timing on my computer it still works, but on his it crashes the macro at "Set htmlColl = ieDOC.getElementsByTagName("a")". I tried moving ie.quit to just before ie2.quit. It it still works on mine, but not on his.